# how to use scipy.integrate to get the volume of a truncated sphere?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm struggling with using scipy.integrate, I used tplquad, but how can I used `integrate` to get the volume of (truncated)sphere? Thanks

```
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import quad, dblquad, tplquad
from math import*
from numpy import *

R = 0.025235 #radius
theta0 = acos(0.023895) #the angle from the edge of truncated plane to the center of
sphere

def f_1(phi,theta,r):
    return r**2*sin(theta)*phi**0
Volume = tplquad(f_1, 0.0,R, lambda y: theta0, lambda y: pi, lambda y,z: 0.0,lambda
y,z: 2*pi)

print Volume
```

Comment: odeint is used for solving differential equation, not integrals. I don't really see, why you want to use it here. Also, you can simplify the integral by integrating out the last two dimensions analytically such that you're left with a single integral.

Answer (score 4):

To truncate by angle it is convenient to use a spherical coordinate systems. Assuming the definition [taken from Arkansas TU](http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/2934/cal1652.pdf) for `radius (r)`, `theta (t)` and `phi (p)` as :
[image: spherical coordinate illustration]

Then, you can truncate setting the limits: `r1` `r2` `t1` `t2` `p1` `p2`:

```
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import quad, dblquad, tplquad
from numpy import *

# limits for radius
r1 = 0.
r2 = 1.

# limits for theta
t1 = 0
t2 = 2*pi

# limits for phi
p1 = 0
p2 = pi

def diff_volume(p,t,r):
    return r**2*sin(p)

volume = tplquad(diff_volume, r1, r2, lambda r:   t1, lambda r:   t2,
                                      lambda r,t: p1, lambda r,t: p2)[0]
```

To truncate by plane it is convenient to use a cartesian coordinate system `(x,y,z)`, where `x**2+y**2+z**2=R**2` ([see mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/kkrSphere.html)). Here I am truncating half of the sphere to demonstrate:

- from `x1=-R` to `x2=R`
- from `y1=0` to `y2=(R**2-x**2)**0.5`
- from `z1=-(R**2-x**2-y**2)**0.5` to `z2=(R**2-x**2-y**2)**0.5`

A useful example using lambdas:

```
R= 2.

# limits for x
x1 = -R
x2 = R

def diff_volume(z,y,x):
    return 1.

volume = tplquad(diff_volume, x1, x2,
                 lambda x: 0., lambda x: (R**2-x**2)**0.5,
                 lambda x,y: -(R**2-x**2-y**2)**0.5,
                 lambda x,y:  (R**2-x**2-y**2)**0.5 )[0]
```