# Triple integration using using Python

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I've been trying to solve an equation using scipy.integrate.tplquadrature but don't fully understand the notation and so don't really know how to solve the following equation. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: IMG]

Thanks,

Comment: [I tried here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28x**2+*+exp%28-x**2%29*exp%28-1*y*z%2F2%2Fx%29%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2Cpi%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2Cinf%7D%2C%7Bz%2C0%2Cinf%7D%29) and it says that this integral does not converge

Answer (score 2):

In your example it gave a zero integral result. I used a high value `1.e22` for `inf`:

```
from scipy import exp, pi
inf = 1.e22
from scipy.integrate import tplquad
func = lambda x,y,z: x**2 * exp(-x**2) * exp(-0.5*y*z/x)
x1,x2 = 0, pi
y1,y2 = lambda x: 0, lambda x: inf
z1,z2 = lambda x,y: 0, lambda x,y: inf
print tplquad( func, x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2 )
#(0.0, 0.0)
```

This is an example [to calculate the volume of a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16884650/832621):

```
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import quad, dblquad, tplquad
from numpy import *
# limits for radius
r1 = 0.
r2 = 1.
# limits for theta
t1 = 0
t2 = 2*pi
# limits for phi
p1 = 0
p2 = pi

def diff_volume(p,t,r):
    return r**2*sin(p)

volume = tplquad(diff_volume, r1, r2, lambda r:   t1, lambda r:   t2,
                                      lambda r,t: p1, lambda r,t: p2)[0]
```

Comment: Is it possible to generate quadrature in 3D or print their directions and weights?